# Is this statement of Mathematical Induction correct?

Tags: induction

Theorem: Principle of Mathematical Induction

For each natural number $n$, let $P(n)$ be a statement. If

1. $P(1)$ is true and
2. $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ for every $k \geq 2$

Then $P(n)$ is true for all $n$.

---

Shouldn't that be $k\geq1$?

Otherwise, I cannot logically conclude $P(2)$'s truth from anything, and thus the chain of modus ponens cannot even be started.

Comment: Right. It should be $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be for each $k\geq1$

Comment: Let $P(n)$ denote the property $n\neq 2$ for a specific counter-example to the current version of the statement.

Comment: @GitGud that's rather hilarious, I think I'll write out this proof below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your formulation of the inductive step 2), it **must** be $k\ge 1$. You can use $k\ge 2$ if you write 
$$
2) \quad P(k-1) \Rightarrow P(k) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the other posters, the statement is wrong, but I want to address Git Gud's idea.

Claim: No natural number is equal to $2$. $(P(n) \iff n \neq 2 )$

We will prove this theorem using the principle of broken induction. First, we see that $P(1)$ is true, since $1 \neq 2$.

Next, we show that $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ for all $k \geq 2$.

Case #1; suppose that $k = 2$. Then $P(k)$ is false, and thus $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ is vacuously true.

Case #2; suppose that $k > 2$. Then $P(k)$ is true, and $k + 1 > 2$. Thus, $k+1 \neq 2$, so $P(k+1)$ is true. Thus, $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ is true.

Since $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ holds for all $k \geq 2$, and $P(1)$ has been shown to be true, the proof is complete.

Thus, no natural number equals $2$.

Comment: This correct application of "broken induction" has (to me at least) a similar feel to "[all horses are the same colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color)".

Comment: I see it as a simple failure to evaluate the base case; for if our induction is on n where n is greater than or equal to 2, the base case is 2, and the truth value of P(1) is wholely irrelevant.